# Bower components and Codekit 2

Tags: javascript, include, bower, codekit

I have recently been getting into using CodeKit, and now version 2 is out, which is what this question regards.  There seems to be great potential in using the bower components installer; however, there is little to no documentation on the working relationship between CodeKit and bower components.  My code follows as:

```
// @codekit-prepend "../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
// @codekit-prepend "../bower_components/PhysicsJS/dist/physicsjs-full-0.6.0.js"

Physics(function(world){

  // code straight out of the example online from the bottom of http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/basic-usage

});
```

Then I get `'Physics' is not defined.` errors on any reference.  This is one example but I seem to always get stuck at this point and I'm wondering: Is there a working way to use prepended libraries through CodeKit's bower components integration?

Comment: Can you update your question to show _where_ you are including the `@codekit-prepend` line? It's not clear if you're including it in the same file as your call to `Physics`. Maybe show more details of what you want for the full file to look like?

Comment: The @codekit-prepend line is in the same file as the Physics call. Do I need to add source map to my compiling of Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though I forgot something quite simple.  It took me hours to figure out that simply adding `$(document).ready(function(){` at the beginning and closing those tags at the end fixed the problem.  Not sure exactly how that works if the libraries are in the same file but I guess it adds a little delay to the execution of the code, allowing the libraries to be considered for the code that follows.